# Custom fstab + grub menu in bootable persistent USB created with mkusb

Tags: grub2, live-usb, fstab, persistence, mkusb

I have created a custom live CD image (erm... live USB, I suppose it'd be more accurate) through a combination of [Cubic](https://linoxide.com/linux-how-to/create-custom-live-cd-image-cubic-ubuntu/) (to generate a custom .iso) and [mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/persistent) to provide it with persistency through a `casper-rw` partition.

It's working really well, but `mkusb` seems to be creating its own `fstab` and its own `grub` menu.

One of the things that `mkusb` does is creating a "regular" NTFS partition so the USB stick can be used as a "regular" storage stick (to save pictures, docs or whatever in it), yet that partition doesn't seem to be mounted on boot.

It would be great if it could be, because I have a pretty specific use I'd like to give to it (specifically, Docker images which now [only seem to work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30427277/289011) properly if I specify [`devicemapper`](https://docs.docker.com/storage/storagedriver/device-mapper-driver/) as the `storage-driver`). It would really, really help if I could have that NTFS partition mounted in `/var/lib/docker/[storage]`, but even if I change `/etc/fstab` while in Cubic, those changes are not reflected in the image that is written to the USB stick.

Something similar happens with the Grub menu. `Cubic` allows to specify your own, but this seems to be overwritten by `mkusb` and because of issues with the computers where the stick is going to be used, it would be great if I could add a `nolapic` flag to the boot line.

Is there any way of doing this?

PS 01: I'm not *married* to `mkusb`... I do like how easy it is to get a persistent USB with it and that works on bios with UEFI boot, though but maybe another tool would give me more control?

PS 02: I don't know much about... anything, really but for this specific use case, let's say I don't know much about persistent partitions on bootable USB sticks.

Comment: 1. You can try if you can mount the NTFS partition manually with a `mount` command line. When that works, you can save the command line(s) to your `~/.bashrc` file, that should make it mount automatically where you want it in the future. There are details about mounting NTFS at [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11840/how-do-i-use-chmod-on-an-ntfs-or-fat32-partition/956072#956072).

Comment: 2. You can add the boot option `nolapic` near the end (like `persistent`) in the line starting with `linux` for each Ubuntu menuentry that you want to use in the file `grub.cfg` in partition #3 of the live USB drive.

Comment: @sudodus, why don't you make that an answer?. I pretty much followed it and it worked. The main difference is that I added the `mount` into my `rc.local` instead of the `.bashrc`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can try if you can mount the NTFS partition manually with a `mount` command line. When that works, you can save the command line(s) to your `~/.bashrc` file, that should make it mount automatically where you want it in the future. There are details about mounting NTFS at [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11840/how-do-i-use-chmod-on-an-ntfs-or-fat32-partition/956072#956072).

   The OP found it better to add the mount into the `rc.local` instead of the `.bashrc`
2. You can add the boot option `nolapic` near the end (like `persistent`) in the line starting with `linux` for each Ubuntu menuentry that you want to use in the file `grub.cfg` in partition #3 of the live USB drive.

Comment: this does not work for a (non-os) USB stick that can be plugged into the PC at any time (before or after boot). Could the answer perhaps be expanded so that the solution would include saving a mountpoint for a removable device too?

Comment: @andrej, Please describe your case with more details in a separate question (and put a link to it here). That makes it easier for me and others to understand how to solve your problem. (In many cases a healthy file system is mounted automatically, when a USB stick is connected, and there can be different reasons why it fails.)

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1503725/automount-a-partition-of-a-usb-stick-in-a-persistent-live-linux-made-with-mkusb